# How to configure two web application in tomcat 7 to use two different realm configured?

Tags: tomcat

I have to deploy two web application to tomcat 7. These two applications use two different realm configured. How can i configure two application to use applicable realm? Both the application is using FORM authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Realm can be scoped to

1. Engine
2. Host
3. Context

   - Context Configuration is applicable for a single application
   - Host can be configured for allowing selective applications to share same realm, Single Sign On SSO can be configured with this
   - Engine can also be configured to allow all applications to use same realm